# Best Order to Read "Ender's Game" Series

Tags: suggested-order, enders-game, orson-scott-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the recommend reading order of the Ender Wiggin books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125/whats-the-recommend-reading-order-of-the-ender-wiggin-books)

Having only read the first novel, I was about to read "Speaker for the Dead" but realized there were many books Card later wrote, which took place in between the first and second book. Should series be read in the order that the author wrote them or in the order the books take place, or some alternative order?