# Is there a reading order of the Enderverse books following Bean's story?

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the recommend reading order of the Ender Wiggin books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125/whats-the-recommend-reading-order-of-the-ender-wiggin-books)

I'm not new to the Enderverse, having read Ender's Game, Ender's Shadow, Speaker for the Dead, Xenocide and Children of the Mind.

Now I've began re-reading them, starting with Ender's Game and currently reading Ender's Shadow. 
I am aware of the regular [recommended reading order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125/whats-the-recommend-reading-order-of-the-ender-wiggin-books) question, but this time I would like to focus on Bean, as I understood there are other books that continue his story and I find him more interesting than Ender.

So I was wondering is there a recommended reading order, or any kind of reading order, for the Enderverse books if one would like to follow Bean's story and not Ender's?
I suspect there aren't any other books particularly about him, like Ender's Shadow was, but he should appear in the other Shadow series novels, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is pretty much a duplicate, but maybe the graphic on that other question wasn't clear enough.

All the stories with "Shadow" in the title are about Bean (but see *Note), and their publication order is the same as chronological order, so that's the obvious sequence to read them in:

- Ender's Shadow (1999)
- Shadow of the Hegemon (2001)
- Shadow Puppets (2002)
- Shadow of the Giant (2005)
- Shadows in Flight (2012)
- Shadows Alive (TBA)

*Note (spoiler for Shadows in Flight) :

> Bean dies in Shadows in Flight, so chances are he won't be in Shadows Alive...

Comment: Actually, the graphic wasn't clear at all regarding the Bean part. I assumed the Shadow stories are about characters like Bean, Peter Wiggins and perhaps other kids from the Battle School. True, I didn't read very much about the Shadow books to avoid spoilers, but I lived under the impression they were mainly about Peter. Anyway, thank you for the answer

Comment: You aren't wrong: Peter and the kids from Battle school are also major characters in the "Shadow" books.

Comment: I understand, even better, I'm looking forward to reading the other books. Thanks for the clarfication